# Why did Michael the Archangel defeat Satan instead of God himself?

Tags: catholicism, satan, revelation, michael

In Revelation 12:7-9 a war breaks out in heaven. Michael and his angels fight against the dragon, who fights back with his angels, but the dragon, named the Devil or Satan, is defeated. The dragon is then thrown out and all his angels with him.

Why, according the Catholic Church, did God not throw the dragon out of Heaven Himself?

Comment: Why have Security and then do the job Oneself ?

Comment: Angels are only ever tools of God, so you can't really say God didn't do it himself.

Comment: A creature dealing with a creature. That is the principle. One who represented God’s authority versus the other

Comment: Michael commands The army of the heavens.  God commands Michael

Comment: A broader perspective of Revelation is always useful.

Comment: I can think of a very good reason for Deity to stand by as two created Beings, of similar rank and privilege, battle for supremacy within their own sphere of operations. But I cannot speak for the Catholic Church on the matter. So you would have to pose the question again and request a Protestant perspective, if you wished my answer.

Comment: This is not an answer, not scripture, and is for 'entertainment' value only: In Paradise Lost, Milton (wrongly, I believe) had the Son cast Satan out after initial battles with Michael and the angels. Satan's despair at realising that the Son was invincible initially almost caused him to repent, before he instead adopted pure, knowingly pointless spite and pride as his motivating factors forevermore. PL actually begins with Satan and the fallen angels reflecting upon it and you only get the back story later on.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any official Church teaching on the matter but the following is a Catholic opinion.

Some people might mistakenly believe that God and Satan are some type of rivals or even equals, however, Satan is merely a created being, infinitely less powerful than God.

God did not defeat Satan Himself primarily because it would not be fitting for him to even acknowledge Satan as worthy of being personally attended to. Just as a mighty Emperor sends his soldiers to quench a petty insurrection so the Almighty sends his angelic army to destroy the forces of evil.

The fact that St. Michael the Archangel was of lower rank emphasizes the humiliation of Satan who used to be the most brilliant of creation.

There are also other considerations that might have prompted God to use St. Michael in this way, such as providing us with an exemplary intercessor for our prayers and shield against evil.

We must not also forget that St. Michael is also a being whose good God desires and, seeing him worthy, he judged it fitting to reward him and exalt him for his humility and courage.

This exaltation in no way diminishes the glory of God since St. Michael in his humility gave himself up to be a mere tool of the Divine Will.

Let us ask for protection from the snares of the Devil by praying the [prophetic  prayer](https://vaticancatholic.com/prayer-saint-michael-pope-leo-xiii/) to St. Michael the Archangel given to Pope Leo XIII which predicted the present apostasy in Rome:

> These most crafty enemies have filled and inebriated with gall and bitterness the Church, the spouse of the immaculate Lamb, and have
> laid impious hands on her most sacred possessions.  In the Holy Place
> itself, where has been set up the See of the most holy Peter and the
> Chair of Truth for the light of the world, they have raised the throne
> of their abominable impiety, with the iniquitous design that when the
> Pastor has been struck, the sheep may be scattered.

I hope my answer was helpful!

Comment: How do the angels fight? Is it with fists, swords or other type of weapons(lightsabers)? What kind of fight or war is it if they are purely spiritual. What is the point of fight if they don't die. Maybe they fight over humans to influence them to avoid or sin. What benefit do they gain by helping or misleading us. Especially for demons there isn't any benefit expect they do it out of hate. But there weren't humans back then...

Comment: @Grasper St. Michael is usually portrayed in armour with a lance or sword. Despite being spiritual beings angels can take on corporal forms. Angels do good because it is good and demons do evil because they are evil. Since it is entirely unreasonable to oppose God, yet the demons did it anyway, it is safe to say they are moved by their sinful inclinations such as pride, jealousy, etc. They can't bear to see humans take their places in heaven. If you wish to read more on Angels there is Suarez's book De Angelis available online in Latin.